# Binary and count variables as endogenous variables

Tags: poisson-distribution, binary-data, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I set up an APIM (actor-partner interdependence model) in R (lavaan).

No I'm facing the following issues:

- 1. Model: My endogenous variable is a count variable that follows a poisson-distribution.
- 2. Model: My endogenous variable is a binary outcome.

Both models work out fine if I just enter them without further specification.

For Model 2 I tried to enter my endogenous variable as ordered:

```r
APIM_H1a_H1b_yesno <- sem(ST_H1a_H1b_yesno, fixed.x=FALSE, data = bef_aft_ana_df, **ordered = c("aftou_yesno", "amtou_yesno")**)
```

However, this lead to the following warning message:

Warnung: lavaan WARNING:
Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
identified.

Did anyone face a similar problem and found a solution?

Comment: `lavaan` has no link function available for modeling counts.  The probit link works for binary outcomes, but there isn't enough information in your post to diagnose the problem.